# Cannot update images in Xcode simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, resources

I would like to update some images (gif) in my application. After replacing the gif files in the folder, I build the application and run it; the images shown in simulator are not updated. I tried to "Clear all target" and then re-built the application; the new images can be shown in the simulator.

Does it mean the images will be successfully updated in the devices which have installed the older version of the application? Should I modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the images in the older version of your applications. You will have to make a fresh release with the new images inorder for the changes to be reflected in your application.

Once the binary is compiled and distributed any changes to the application can be done by rebuilding and submitting the application. However if you are doing testing only then delete the app and reinstall after a clean build.

Hope this clears things for you.

Comment: Thanks Praveen:) Actually I would like update an app in app store. What I want is just update some images in the app and everything else remain unchanged. But I found that I have to "Clear all target" in order to see the new images in simulator. I concern if my customers able to see the new images by simply installing the new version of app in App Store.

Comment: Yes they will be able to see new images if you change them, do a clean build, create a new version of the app, upload it to apple.

Comment: Yup Any new submission will override the old submission. Whats that app btw ;-).